Total probability of drawing 3 identical cards
Late midnight call for help.
I have 52 cards, 13 unique cards in 4 suits.
What is the probability that I draw 3 identical cards (irrespective of suit), and two other cards (doesn’t matter if same or not).
I can calculate the probability for a specific sample of 5 cards drawn without replacement from the deck of 52, where 3 cards are the same: 0.000177
However, my brain tells me that it’s only the probability for 1 particular sequence of cards pulled from the deck (e.g. A1, A2, A3, 1, 9). There are other ways of pulling the same cards in a different order after each experiment (7,A1,A2,8,A4), each of approximate same probability 0.000177.
There are also 4 groups of 3 unique cards pulled from 4 different sets (e.g., Queen Hearts, Spades, etc.) when order doesn’t matter. So, my brain tells me that each time a unique trio from the set of 4 identical cards (suit differs) appears in a sample of 5 without replacement, the 3 cards can be arranged in X number of unique ways without replacement and where order matters.
So, doesn’t the probability of pulling 3 identical cards, accounting for all possible orders, have to account for all the unique groups of 3 cards, as well as for all the ways they can be ordered in a set , to calculate the total probability of 3 identical cards happening accounting for all potential orders of appearance?
Seems logical to me, but it also seems like the total probability becomes too high to be be making sense. Help ‍

You should say whether you are including 4 of a kind in your count.  In usual poker terms,  specifying one type of hand precludes superior hands ( a royal flush isn't counted as a straight,  for example).

52 cards, 13 unique cards repeating in 4 separate suits. There are 4 instances of a kind of card for each card (e.g., 1 Hearts, 1 Spades, etc.). Only 3 instances out of the 4 appear in the sample of 5 cards drawn without replacement from the deck of 52 cards. 4 identical cards can make 4 unique trios of cards (order doesn’t matter, only which cards without repetition). So, it can apply to any kind of card type (Queens, Kings, Ones).

My question was simple.  Does 4 of a kind count or not? The answer should be yes or no. Your question makes it clear that you are including full houses.

So, you haven't state, but does this mean you draw $5$ cards? Ask the question as clearly as possible, and don't rely on people knowing poker.

The count depends on the sample space, if you sample space is just all possible unordered sets of five cards, then you don't care about the order of the specific cards. If the sample space is of ordered lists of 5 cards, then you have to consider the order of the cards are drawn. Either works, but unordered is simpler, I think. Also, do you want to rule out full houses?

I get $$\binom{13}1\cdot\binom{4}3\cdot\binom{12}{2}\cdot \binom41^2/\binom{52}5$$


I try to find 0.000177, same as you, and I am not able. 2) You need to go step by step. What is the probability to obtain exactly A-spade, A-Diamond, A-Club and 2 cards (excluding Aces)  (A1, then A2, thenA3, then 2 other cards) ; Q2) same, without order , etc etc , until you obtain the final result.


@"Thomas Andrews", (Ace, Ace, Ace,2,2) should be considered as ok.

I assume this is a poker draw, so you pick five cards from the deck without replacement. You can't get the ace of spades twice.

I would use "ranks" instead of "cards." The ace of spades is a card, the ace is the rank of a card.

@lulu I didn't get it initially, since I don't play poker nor am interested in cards :D This case study is pulled from a university homework and since I got a lousy prob/math.stat. prof., here I am begin for collective intelligence. Answer is: no, no 4 of a kind allowed. Number of identical cards must be exactly 3, not 3 and more.

@Lourran, Example: prob of A1, A2, A3, B1, B2, where any A is another instance of the same card (e.g., Queen, 4 of them), B is any other card that isn't an instance of A. First draw: 4/52, Second: 3/51, Third: 2/50, Fourth: 48/49, Fifth: 47/48. If you multiply these probs together, you get 0.000174.

You have explained things in comments that should be edited into the question.

There are 13 possibilities for the kind of the three cards. For each kind, the probability of finding exactly three of them in the sample is
$\begin{equation}p_1=\frac{\tbinom {4}{3}\cdot\tbinom {48}{2}}{\tbinom {52}{4}} = \frac{4\cdot1128}{2598960} = 0.001736\end{equation}$
Since these possibilities refer to disjoint events, the probability we are looking for is the sum of these probabilities, i.e. $\hspace{3pt}=13\cdot p_1=0.0226$

This is incorrect. The first card drawn does not need to be part of the set.

OK, the three cards do not need to be of the same kind as the first card drawn, they can also match the second or third card. I ignored these possibilities in my first attempt to solve the problem. Hopefully I have now taken these cases into account

I get
$$\frac{N}{D} ~: ~D = \binom{52}{5},$$
where
$$N = \binom{13}{1} \times \binom{4}{3} \times \binom{48}{2}. \tag1 $$
In (1) above, the first two factors identify the rank and which of three of the 4 cards in that rank will be selected.  Then, regardless of the rank chosen, there will be $~48~$ remaining cards, from which $~2~$ must be chosen.

What is the probability that I draw 3 identical cards (irrespective of suit), and two other cards (doesn’t matter if same or not).

The $~\displaystyle \binom{48}{2}~$ factor is consistent with it not mattering whether the two other cards are the same rank.

Honestly, could be. I modeled the case study I describe using R and repeating the experiment 1000 times. I get 19 instances of 3 identical cards out of 1000, so a prob. of 0.019. With your answer, prob. is 0.022, so very close to my modeled result. I don't get the logic of the calculation yet because I have the lousiest professor ever who dumps info on us and good luck figuring it out, but I will work on breaking down your approach, hoping it's the correct one :-)

Not so close, simulation is less by $3/22, \approx 13.64%$ !
